# Making validation for both text field and checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Please can I ask for help with my form. I am wanting to make both the text fields and check box required fields. The check box is validating, all I need now is for the text fields to require validation. I'm using javascript.

HTML:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="result.php" onSubmit="return checkme()">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>Name: </td>
<td> <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email: </td>
<td> <input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agree_terms"> I agree to the terms</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">      <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
<!--//hide script
function checkme() {
missinginfo = "";
if (!document.form.agree.checked) {
missinginfo += "\n - You must agree to the terms";
}
if (missinginfo != "") {
missinginfo ="__________________________________\n" +
"Required information is missing: \n" +
missinginfo + "\n__________________________________" +
"\nPlease complete and resubmit.";
alert(missinginfo);
return false;
}
else {
return true;
}
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this JS code for validating the text field

```
if(document.form.Name.value==""){
missinginfo += "Required field";
}
```

Same for e-mail field also.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert you doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` then you can use

```
required="true"
```

It will be implemented as follow

```
<input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="20" required="true">
```

Most browsers support HTML5. Alternatively make use of [jQuery validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) which is fairly simple to use.